# How to create notification on particular date and time inside a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification

My fragment class contains the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);

intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);

intent.putExtra("todo",hello);

PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();

startTime.set(2018,3,18,20,30,0);

long alarmStartTime = startTime.getTimeInMillis();

alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime, alarmIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver.class contains as follows.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Get id & message from intent.
    int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("todo");

    // When notification is tapped, call MainActivity.
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, 0);

    NotificationManager myNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Prepare notification.
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle("It's Time!")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    // Notify
    myNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());

}
}
```

On running the app, the Notification is not created on 18-april-2018 @ 8.30 pm

Suggest me some changes so that I can run this app well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's currently hard to understand what you're asking. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described. And could you please have a look at your code formatting?

Comment: i want to simply generate a notification on specified date and time through a fragment class. Can you give me a short code to do this.. I will be grateful to you

Comment: Do you have a `<receiver>` element in the manifest for `AlarmReceiver`? If so, is it in the right spot; i.e., between the `<application>` tags, but not inside any others? Is the Receiver running at all? How are you determining that, either way? Which version of Android are you testing on? Starting with API level 26 (Oreo), `Notification`s require that you use channels.

Comment: Thanks MIKE... <receiver> tag was missing from my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

try to change the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`

to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

I hope this helps

Comment: no... nothing happened